# Avoiding Nested For Loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am stuck with scenarios where i am unable to think Out of box on how to avoid Nested FOR loop scenario for my use case. I am Implementing a Equipment Automation script where am using GPIB conn (PyVisa) to interact with those equipments,

I have a config file which defines the length of below three list to be used in Looping, 
Total_subDie_cnt = 5

```
#Loop Through all SubDie
for subdie in range(int(confObj.get('Total_Subdie'))):
    print('\tTesting SubDie Num : ', str(subdie))
    if (subdie > 0):
        #Move to the First/Next SubDie only if not at the First SubDie
        Prob.moveSubDie(subdie) #Sending Command to Equipment via Prob Module

    for x in range(confObj.get('Structure_Cnt')):
        struc = str(parseObj.struc_type[x]) #Get Structure Type of current structure
        struc_name = str(parseObj.struc_name[x]) #Get Structure Name of current structure
        module_list = module_table.get(struc).split(',') #Get Total Number of module count for current structure
        Prob.moveStructure(parseObj.struc_X[x], parseObj.struc_Y[x]) # Move to current strcuture Location via Prob Module

        for y in range(len(module_list )):
            Prob.moveOpticalSubDie(module_list[y]) #Move to specific module
            #After moved to required location Measurement is performed
```

When it comes to second FOR loop i have a list which capture the structure Name of the current structure in loop (eg.) structure_Name[structure] and based on the structure_Name i will decide on the Total_module_cnt value to be used in the third FOR loop.

Any suggestion on how to fasten up this process, currently its taking too many interation x*y*z as the range for each count increases.

Thanks

Comment: If your goal is to make the algorithm faster, then it depends entirely on what you are doing in the loop, and what your requirements are for the solution.

Comment: Hi @kaya3, my main objective is indeed to fasten up the algorithm but also to improve readability of the code itself. As in specifics to what it does inside each loop is already optimized (They are just sending some commands to respective equipments). For example inside the first For Loop, i send command to move to subdie 0 to the equipment (It know the location corresponding to subdie 0) and so on. So is the same for 2nd FOR loop Move to structure 0 and most of calculation happen inside Inner-Most FOR loop but independent of Outer FOR loop result

Comment: So show us the full code for your algorithm. The current code in your question does nothing, so it can be sped up by just deleting it; that is not the answer you want, but a more useful answer isn't possible without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi @kaya3, i have added some more code snippet for better understanding. The content of third FOR loop is just communication with multiple equipment and performing measurement.

Comment: OK. Is there a reason the loops need to be nested? The variables `subdie` and `x` aren't used in the other loops.

Comment: Hi @kaya3 , The Outer For loops are mainly used to move the robot handler to the assigned location before making the measurement in the third Loop. So, i thought of using Nested Loop as each step follows after the previous one, It cannot be performed in parallel. Like it needs to go to the Correct Sub Die first, follows by correct structure and then resume measurement